# Passing data back to previous Fragment with Android Navigation Components

Tags: android

Imagine that `FragmentA` starts `FragmentB` on a button click. Passing some arguments to `FragmenB` is pretty straightforward:

```
 val action = FragmentADirections.actionToFragmentB("some text")
 findNavController().navigate(action)
```

But is there a way to pass data from `FragmentB` to `FragmentA` when the user navigates away from `FragmentB`? With other words, when `FragmentB` is destroyed as the result of back press.

Answer (score 0):

In your Navigation UI xml:

```
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/FragmentB"
        android:name="com.example.FragmentB"
        android:label="FragmentB"
        tools:layout="@layout/FragmentA">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_FragmentB_to_FragmentA"
            app:destination="@id/FragmentA" />
    </fragment>
```

Like you want to navigate with some arguments back to the **FragmentA** from **FragmentB**, use this:

```
        findNavController().navigate(
            R.id.action_FragmentB_to_FragmentA,
            bundleof("key" to <your_value>) // example: 100 (Int value)
            )
```

Then you can **just** receive the argument in your **FragmentA** using `arguments?.getInt("key")` or if you pass `String` can get it with `arguments?.getString("str_key")` etc.